# Banach Lattices and the Fatou property: can I always find disjoint positive elements with large norms?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-lattices

Suppose I have a lattice $X$ with a weak Fatou norm, meaning that there exists some constant $M$ (clearly $\geq 1$) such that for all $x\geq 0$ and for all increasing nets $x_\alpha$ with $x_\alpha \uparrow x$, we have $ \| x \| \leq M \| x_\alpha \| $.  Under what conditions do there exist disjoint elements $0 \leq y ,z \leq x$ where both $y$ and $z$ have relatively "large" norms?  That is, is there some $K > 0$ such that  if $\|x \| = 1$, I can ensure that for some positive, disjoint $y$ and $z$ bounded by $x$ we have **both** $\|y\| \geq K$ and $\|z\| \geq K$?  I've tried looking through the main literature but can't find anything specific to this.

Fatouness is important here, since it can affect the size of the smallest norm.  For example,  If $X$ is the sublattice of $c$ of convergent sequences $(a_1,a_2,...)$ where $M \lim_n a_n =a_1$.  Then if you have the sequence $(1, 1/M,1/M,...)$, the most $K$ can be is $1/M$, since any element $x$ containing $a_1 > 0$ must also contain cofinitely many $a_n$'s, leaving $y$ with only finite support.  On the other hand, a lattice without such a norm might not guarantee any such positive $K$ (see for example, a $c_0$ sum of the lattices above with increasing $M\in \mathbb N$).

Comment: I am not aware that this question has been studied. This property fails for sequence spaces because if $0\leq f,g\leq \delta_k$ and $f\perp g$, then $f=0$ or $g=0$. On the other hand, it should hold for $L^p([0,1])$ because the measure space is divisble.

Comment: Yeah this clearly won't work for the atoms in sequence spaces, as $K=0$ characterizes atoms.  The context where this came up for me involved atomless spaces, and I was wondering to what extent an element could "approximate" the behavior of an atom even in an atomless space, or in the case of atomic spaces, if approximation implied closeness to an atom.   The case of $L_p([0,1])$ is the opposite in that you can get $K = 1/2^{1/p}$, so not only are there no atoms, no element is even "approximately" atomic.